# JSON schema with references: why is a required field not found?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I use a JSON schema that should define a screen with an arbitrary number of buttons:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Screen": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Widgets": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "required": true,
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/properties/Button"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Button": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the JSON I validate against:

```
{
    "Screen": {
        "Widgets": [
            {
                "Button": {
                    "title": "10"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I use http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/ as validator and here I get the following error:

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/Button"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/Screen/Widgets/0"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "properties",
  "message" : "missing required property(ies)",
  "required" : [ "title" ],
  "missing" : [ "title" ]
} ]
```

The required field `title` is reported as missing, although it is in the JSON. 
I assume that I have made something wrong with the referencing of `Button`, but I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Because according with your schema, each element in Widgets array must conform to the schema defined in #/properties/Button. 
This schema says that each Button must be a Json Object with a required property called "title". In code:

```
{"title": "10"}
```

But you have provided a Json Object with a Property called "Button", which is not the restriction you specified.

Beware you are using Json-schema draft03, you should have a look at draft04, although it is not different for this case.

Comment: It's a *little* different - specifically the use of `required`.

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON for given schema is:
`

```
{
  "Screen": {
    "Widgets": [
      {
        "title": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`